# asp.net-mvc save excel file to specific location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-disposition

I have the following code that downloads a file to the client's machine and it works great. However, I also need to ask the user where they want to save the file before the download begins.

Is this something I do in the action method (someone in the below code) or is this an option the client has to set on his/her browser and independent of what my code does?

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(filePath + fileName);
response.Flush();

response.End();
```

Comment: Side note: since you've marked question ASP.Net MVC consider using [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or sibling `FilePathResult` instead of manually constructing response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "this an option the client has to set on his/her browser and independent of what my code does".

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, that is the responsibility/behavior of the browser. If you want more client side control, you would have to write a client side app to save off to a specific location, or (easier) have the end user configure their browser to ask where to save downloads to.

Comment: what do you mean by a client side app? you mean something using javascript?

Comment: More like an unsandboxed app that would handle the HttpRequest (like a Winforms or WPF app).  Ultimately the first answer is correct, it's a browser setting that the end user/client administrator will have to configure for the browser.